# Exception: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am sorry if this question irritates you. I had been trying to solve for so long. I still could not find the difference between the "Expected" and "Found".

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: question(com.bangladroid.drivingtest.database.model.Question).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='question', columns={image=Column{name='image', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, question=Column{name='question', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer=Column{name='answer', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer3=Column{name='answer3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer2=Column{name='answer2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, favorite=Column{name='favorite', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer1=Column{name='answer1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='question', columns={image=Column{name='image', type='integer', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, question=Column{name='question', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer=Column{name='answer', type='integer', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer3=Column{name='answer3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer2=Column{name='answer2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, favorite=Column{name='favorite', type='integer', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, answer1=Column{name='answer1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Is there any difference between "integer" and "INTEGER"? what does primaryKeyPosition mean?

Comment: Did you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference between "integer" and "INTEGER"?

**No** column types are case insensitive.

> I still could not find the difference between the "Expected" and "Found".

The difference is that the **_id** column is defined differently.

`primaryKeyPosition=1` (expected) v
`primaryKeyPosition=0` (found)

So you need to make the pre-packaged database define the **_id** column to include `PRIMARY KEY`. (Room requires that an Entity(table) has a primary key defined so the Entity cannot be changed to suit).